# MySql phpMyAdmin: Replicating/Synchronizng two Database automatically

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, synchronization

I have two same database on two different server, and I want to synchronize both database.

For example, If I do any process like Insert, Update, Delete, Alter, Drop, etc it also reflect on other database automatically.

I had tried it on my local server, but every time I have to do it manually.

Is there any way to do it automatically, suppose I Insert a record and it automatically inserted into other database.

Comment: Search for `MySQL Master Master replication`.

Answer (score 3):

The "synchronisation" feature you are looking for is called **[Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html)**.

A replication can be set up between a `master` and a `slave` machine.

It does not rely on a constant connection, but stores all changes on the master and replays all those changes on the slave once a connection is established.

[***Tuturial for you***](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is called 'Replication'.

If you are going to be making changes to both databases and expect it to show up in the other, you need a Master/Master pair.

Have a read about it here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/best-way-to-setup-master-to-multi-master-replication